# ESP8266 AT commands working but Fatal on NodeMCU

Tags: lua, wifi, iot, esp8266, nodemcu

**Hardware**: ESP8266-1

**Settings in IDE**

```
Module: ESP8266-1
Flash Size: 4MB
Flash Mode: DIO
Flash Speed: 40Mhz
Upload Using: Arduino FTDI Serial
```

Firmware installed :

```
nodemcu_integer_0.9.5_20150318.bin      : 0X00000
```

(Also tried with latest firmware nodemcu_integer_0.9.6-dev_20150627.bin)

Error : (Esplorer)

```
PORT OPEN 115200

Communication with MCU…
……….
……….
Got answer! AutoDetect firmware…
Communication with MCU established.
Can’t autodetect firmware, because proper answer not received (may be unknown firmware).
Please, reset module or continue.

Fatal exception (0):
epc1=0x40210880, epc2=0x00000000, epc3=0x00000000, excvaddr=0x00000000, depc=0x00000000
Fatal exception (0):
epc1=0x40210880, epc2=0x00000000, epc3=0x00000000, excvaddr=0x00000000, depc=0x00000000
```

PS : I'm using a separate 3.3V power supply from beaglebone.
I'm able to flash the module with NoduMCU (above settings without any error)

Module works fine with AT commands

```
boot_v1.6.bin                           : 0X00000
esp_init_data_default.bin               : 0XFC000
blank.bin                               : 0XFE000
user1.1024.new.2.bin                    : 0x1000
```

But not able to program Lua in my module.

Please help!!!

Comment: Don't use those outdated 0.9.x releases, they're outdated and no longer supported. http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/#getting-started has instructions as for how to build the firmware and flash it to your device (too long to repeat here).

Comment: Out of above mentioned 4 binaries are there any binary which is compulsory other than those module available in custom build option od NodeMCU, like esp_init_default (i'm not sure of this). If yes what is the correct address of those to program for NodeMCU ? 
And where shall i program/Flash this custom firmware , at 0x0000 ??

Thanks

Comment: All those questions are answered in the flashing docs referenced in my previous comment.

Comment: Ok. I did that, selected these 6 modules : file, gpio, net, tmr, uart, wifi..
Combined nodemcu-master-6-modules.bin is programed at 0x0000 But i get no help (even with diff bauds)
At 9600 & 115200baud
<▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒wwc=c▒▒RS▒fJS▒fJ▒j▒▒▒<▒▒
                                       ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒x8▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒xwc_▒R▒fJS▒fJ▒j

However @MarcelStör my module once worked perfectly with nodemcu_integer_0.9.5_20150318.bin but now i don't remember config etc and it's not re-working with NodeMCU. But module is still working fine with AT command binaries. What can be probable issue ?

Comment: @MarcelStör I'm still getting 

Fatal exception (0):
epc1=0x40210880, epc2=0x00000000, epc3=0x00000000, excvaddr=0x00000000, depc=0x00000000

With nodeMCU for  esp-01.